# How can I create a pseudo interface or class for "joining" real classes

Tags: java

I'd like to declare a variable that could be an object of `x.y.z.z.y.Foo`, `x.y.z.z.y.Bar` or `x.y.z.z.y.Baz`. If these classes were maintained by me, I'd create a class (e.g. `x.y.z.z.y.Nice`), so my variable would be declared as `Nice variable`. But the `x.y.z.z.y` package is a 3rd-party library (https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java, to be exact), so I can't make this library's classes implementing the `Nice` interface.

Is there a way to define some pseudo-interface/-class to have been assured that the variable could hold an object of certain classes of a 3rd-party library?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wrap it (or them) in a shell interface/class, perhaps simply delegating methods, or delegate underneath something that makes sense in your domain.

Answer (score 5):

I'd probably write a facade class to encapsulate the use of the 3rd-party package. Then that facade class and your other classes can all implement the `Nice` interface.

(A side benefit is that if you decide to switch to using some other 3rd-party package instead of the current one, you only have to change the facade class, not everything that uses it.)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I do, but the point is that __inside__ of this class I'd like to manipulate with some class kind of `KubernetesObject` rather than `Object`. :-)

Comment: @VolodymyrMelnyk - At that implementation level, you're going to need to have separate variables and branch (or use `Object` and reflection).